# Maximum filesize for e-mail attachments using JMail (Classic ASP)

Tags: asp-classic, jmail

What is the maximum file size for an attachment in JMail 4.5. I use the function `AddURLAttachment()`.

I'm getting the following error:

```
jmail.SMTPMail error '8000ffff' 

The message was undeliverable. All servers failed to receive the message
```

I've checked the SMTP logs on the SMTP host; there is an entry that the message exceeded the maximum size. So that means that is not a problem with JMail, right? More like a problem with the SMTP settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think there is a maximum size for attachments in jMail. The only thing is that a lot of mailserver have a limit. To be safe I would stay below 10mb.

Did you run into an error when trying to attach something?

Comment: I get an Internal Server Error (500) if I try to add an attachment that is 6.7MB. The same script does work for a file that is 600KB.

Comment: Any change you can get the exact error message? Internal Server Error is a generic error message.

Comment: I executed the script on the server where it is hosted; updated my original question.

Comment: You were right, the mailserver had a maximum message size of 5 MB.